# How to forecast in Power BI using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a chart in excel I wish to replicate in PBI.

My Excel chart is a bar chart dated axis with 2 series, running up march, but with data only up until now.

Each bar series has a trendline, which forecasts a trend up to the end of the financial year.

In power BI I have tried to replicate, but I cannot seem to add 'forecast' from the analytics tab unless my chart is a line graph.

So I now have 2 line series in a chart like so:

[image]

I have added trendline to both but there is no option to add the forecast line unless I only have 1 data series.

As I've removed a series I can now toggle on the forecast line in the analytics tab.

So I now have 1 line series in my line graph like so:

[image]

I actually need to have the data and the corresponding forecast for both data series, so I would have series 1 & 2 plotted like above, on the same graph together.

Is there a way to do this on the analytics tab??
If not, how should I go about it? I was thinking I could use DAX to forecast until March 2023 instead and then drag the line into the line graph and format it to dashed?

Thanks

Here is some sample data step by step for what i'm looking for (very simple thing to do in excel!):

[image]

This is the same data, pivoted with the 2 series mapped out on a line graph, and trendline added for each:
[image]

I just want to be able to show a trendline extending and forecasting forward, past the months I already have like I have done in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

For a forecasting line to be performed on a line chart, Below requirements should be met. Otherwise You can't see this option on the analytics tab:

[image: GRGE]

You need to change your datasets, and datatypes accordingly.
The last one is especially valid for you, because there is not a one-day period between your data values, in fact monthly organized.

[image: DFD]

[image: DFFG]

Comment: thank you for your response. I have attached a screenshot in my example where i have been able to forecast with just one line in my line chart. However I need to forecast 2. When I add my 2nd data series, the forecast option gets removed. I need to be able to forecast both in one chart, so I imagine I need to create 2 seperate measures that I can drag into the charts and format as dashed. Please refer to question. Can you help?

Comment: @Rebecca If you believe that this will solve your problem, Then why don't you try and see it for yourself. DAX Measures you need is simple: Measure_Azure =
CALCULATE ( SUM ( YourTable[Target Sum] ), YourTable[Source] = "Azure" ) and the other: Measure_AWS =
CALCULATE ( SUM ( YourTable[Target Sum] ), YourTable[Source] = "AWS" ).

Comment: I'm quite new to Power BI, so thanks for pointing me in the right direction with the DAX. I will try this ASAP and come back to you!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i think here your best solution would be to use the "what if" parameter in Dax to get the result you need

Comment: My table is 'CombinedUsage' and my Data series I wish to forecast until March 2023 is where 'CombinedUsage'[Source] = "AWS"... Could you help?

Comment: this would require a sample data, or more details

Comment: thanks, i have edited my question with sample data